# Error during build( tool-ant ) with JAXB2.0 upgraded version ( removed globalBindingstyle from script )

Tags: xml, ant, jaxb

Recently I have upgraded to JAXB2.0 i.e.. I have replaced jaxb-api, jaxb-impl, jaxb-xjc to 2.2.11 and added jaxb-core.jar.

When I do build using ant( 1.9.2 ), I got error global Bindings:

> [ERROR] xx: Attribute 'bindingStyle' is not allowed to appear in
>   element 'jxb:globalBindings'..

I learned that global bindings are no longer allowed in JAXB version >=2.0 ([Reference](https://www.java.net/node/659089)).

So, I removed `"jxb:globalBindings bindingStyle="modelGroupBinding" choiceContentProperty="true"` and rebuilt it.

I now have 7 errors. One of the errors is:

> error: cannot find symbol FieldOrMixinGroup fieldOrMixin =
>   (FieldOrMixinGroup) iterator.next();

Any help will be appreciated.